# What is the right site for my question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask a question regarding the (automatic) installation of .NET FrameWork in the installer of my application.

Basically I want to know whether it is possible to do it with an (open-source) installer.

But I don't know what the right site for it is.

It's not specifically programming related (SO), but I also don't know if it suits SU (nor whether people on SU will be able to help me).

What do you guys say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementation questions like this are off-topic on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com): higher-level questions, like whether you ought to install the .NET framework with your application, would be Programmers material.

For implementation questions, you want to ask on Stack Overflow. Indeed, there have been [several hundred similarly-scoped questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=installing+.net&submit=search) already.

Answer (score 1):

Considered that an installer is created from who deploy applications, I would say it is a question about a programming tool. You could ask the question on Stack Overflow, or Programmers, depending on the exact question: If the question is about actual code you are writing, then it could be asked on Stack Overflow; if the question is more conceptual, then it could suit Programmers.

Programmers' FAQ report the following list of acceptable questions:

- algorithm and data structure concepts
- design patterns
- developer testing
- development methodologies
- freelancing and business concerns
- quality assurance
- software architecture
- software engineering
- software licensing